# Fresh install of 13.10 - left with no dash nor apps - only blank magenta wallpaper

Tags: unity, unity-dash, startup-applications

Regarding recently installed ubuntu desktop 13.10 (40gb HDD and plenty RAM) as a fresh install on an appropriately partitioned HDD.

My problem is that once installed everything is blank: no dash, no launcher, no apps, just a blank magenta wallpaper loads.

Its infuriating because nothing works..I've tried suggestions on many threads and am pretty new to terminal. 
As it is right now, its a useless operating system as far as my needs go and I don't see why it has to be so extremely difficult to install.

If this is a duplicate question (none of the suggested duplicates have this exact question, and the ones that are similar have either no answers or the few answers they do have, have not been successful at fixing my problem). So if an exact duplicate is found *with workable answers*, I'd really appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are describing sounds like the Unity 3D desktop is not working. This could be because your hardware is not powerful enough for it or another issue with graphics.

I would try an install of Lubuntu 31.10: http://www.lubuntu.net/

-or-

Ubuntu 12.04.3 and use Unity 2D by slecting it at the login screen by clicking the icon in the top right of the login box: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop